# Can we select one less than all columns from table

Tags: sql-server, plsql

Please help me:
I have 100 columns in a table & i want to select 99 columns but i don't want to write 99 columns. Is there any way.

Thanks in advance,
Nishant Khanna

Comment: No. Define the names of the **all** columns you want, or return them all with `*`. There is no "`* (EXCEPT ID)`" functionality.

Comment: Use a databae management software to generate select top(100) rows. They generally create a query specifying each column

Comment: Also, you've tagged SQL Server and PLSQL. PLSQL is used by Oracle and SQL Server uses T-SQL. What is your question about here?

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL:

```
declare @schema varchar(128)
declare @table varchar(128)
declare @exceptedColumn varchar(128)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @schema = 'dbo'
set @table = 'MyTable'
set @exceptedColumn = 'DontWantThat'

set @sql = 'SELECT ' + (
select STUFF((select ',' + '[' + columns.name + ']' from sys.columns
join sys.tables on tables.object_id = columns.object_id
join sys.schemas on schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
where schemas.name = @schema and tables.name = @table and columns.name <> @exceptedColumn
for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
) + ' FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + ']'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than dumping everything into tempdb. I would suggest using `QUOTENAME` over `[' + @objectname + ']'` (thus `QUOTENAME(@objectname)`). Thus means that if anyone has (foolishly) created an object with a really silly characters (like a `]`) the code won't break

Comment: This solution works only in case, when caller has at least db owner rights on database. At most cases your procedures are executed from other scope than sysadmin or db owner.  Now you are experimenting in SSMS with sysadmin, yeah? In production it will be executed using login/database role/role execution rights. And, there will be surprise. Figure out this ;)
Hint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-2017)
The visibility of metadata is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For example, the following query returns a row if the user has been granted a permission such as SELECT or INSERT on the table myTable.
`SELECT name, object_id  
FROM sys.tables  
WHERE name = 'myTable';  
GO`
If I'm getting it right, there will no be problem, if user has permission for select from that table.

Comment: Standard practice is to give login access to database user, and database user assign to database role. And database role allow to execute procedure. Not give select on table (it is bad practice!), but give execute rights on procedure. In this case we have problem. And, this is mostly used standard good practice. So, be careful at this point.

Comment: @Juozas - if the user doesn't have permissions to select from a table, this entire question becomes moot because it's all predicated on wanting to write a select on the table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, if we are talking about direct query execution using SSMS and F5. And absolotely no, if code used for example in stored procedure, and executed from other scope, than your current powerfull admin connection :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select * into [#my_table] from [my_table];
alter table [#my_table] drop column [my_column];
select * from [#my_table];
```

Comment: That a really bad way to not return the value of one column. If that table is big, that is going to be awfully slow.

Comment: You always can restrict your recordset by using where clause. We all understand, that I provided pattern how to solve problem, right?

Comment: Yes, it'll solve the problem, but that doesn't mean it's a good solution.

Comment: So, imagine that the 99 columns are `bit` and the 100th column (the one they want to omit) is `nvarbinary(max)` and every row has a full 2GB of content in that column. You query first has to allocate enough space in `tempdb` for the *entire* contents of the table, even though you only want 0.0001% of the data.

Comment: Please provide better solution, we all learn from it. As said before - most of problems can be avoided using strict where clause. This solution potentially covers most of needs. And sure, we can generate tons of whatabout cases, why this is bad :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Replace the **TableName** with yours and Column name that you don't want in your query.
```

**This will surely work**

```
     SELECT left(replace((
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ','
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME = '**TableName**'
                        FOR XML path('')
                        ), '**Column_Name_That_You_Don't want in your query**' + ',', ''), (
                    len(replace((
                                SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ','
                                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                WHERE TABLE_NAME = '**TableName**'
                                FOR XML path('')
                                ), '**Column_Name_That_You_Don't want in your query**' + ',', ''))
                    ) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the 99 columns and use that in your code instead of the actual table.